# How i get value another class when i using @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 class. Requests and Services class.

Requests class.

```
import com.eziz.clients.Clients;
import com.eziz.services.Services;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
public class Requests {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long requestId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
    private String requestComment;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String requestStatus;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String requestExpiryTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String requestDateCreated;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestClientId")
    private Clients client;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestServiceId")
    private Set<Services> service = new HashSet<>();

//    @ManyToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "requestService")
//    private Services services;
//
    public Long getRequestId() {
        return requestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(Long requestId) {
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    public String getRequestComment() {
        return requestComment;
    }

    public void setRequestComment(String requestComment) {
        this.requestComment = requestComment;
    }

    public String getRequestStatus() {
        return requestStatus;
    }

    public void setRequestStatus(String requestStatus) {
        this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
    }

    public String getRequestExpiryTime() {
        return requestExpiryTime;
    }

    public void setRequestExpiryTime(String requestExpiryTime) {
        this.requestExpiryTime = requestExpiryTime;
    }

    public String getRequestDateCreated() {
        return requestDateCreated;
    }

    public void setRequestDateCreated(String requestDateCreated) {
        this.requestDateCreated = requestDateCreated;
    }

    public Clients getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Clients client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Set<Services> getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Set<Services> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Service Class.

```
package com.eziz.services;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
public class Services {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long serviceId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String serviceCategory;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double servicePrice;

    public Long getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public void setServiceId(Long serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getServiceCategory() {
        return serviceCategory;
    }

    public void setServiceCategory(String serviceCategory) {
        this.serviceCategory = serviceCategory;
    }

    public double getServicePrice() {
        return servicePrice;
    }

    public void setServicePrice(double servicePrice) {
        this.servicePrice = servicePrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.serviceName;
    }
}
```

Now i get serviceName with ManyToMany in Service class.
But i can not get another value.i am need do this without toString.

```
<div class="modal header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Request Details</h5>
    <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
            type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="content content-fixed content-auth">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="tx-color-01 mg-b-5" align="center">
            SIFARIŞ MƏLUMATLARI </h1>
        <hr>
        <table class="table">
            <tr th:object="${request}">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Sifariş ID</th>
                <td scope="col" data-label="Sifariş ID" th:text="${request.requestId}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Qeydiyyat tarixi</th>
                <td data-label="Qeydiyyat tarixi" th:text="${request.requestDateCreated}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Xidmət</th>
                <td data-label="Xidmət" th:text="${request.service}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Təhvil vermə zamanı</th>
                <td data-label="Təhvil vermə zamanı" th:text="${request.requestExpiryTime}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Rəy</th>
                <td data-label="Rəy" th:text="${request.requestComment}"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <td data-label="Status" th:text="${request.requestStatus}"></td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Bağla</button>
</div>
```

I dont can get value when i doing this.

```
  <tr>
                <th scope="col">Xidmət</th>
                <td data-label="Xidmət" th:text="${request.service.serviceCategory}"></td>
            </tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
                <th scope="col">Xidmət</th>
                <td data-label="Xidmət" th:text="${request.service.serviceCount}"></td>
            </tr>
```

how i can do this? How i can get request.service.serviceCount or serviceCategory or serviceName
when i doing request.service this only coming serviceName, because i write here toString method return this.serviceName . i can get all of them with toString method. But i am need separately.

Comment: What do you want to do? I did not understand

Comment: @Zaur mən Service class-ını Request class-ında istifadə etmişəm və request yaradanda olan servisləri seçirəm. O servisləri görmək üçün də, request.service yazıb çağırıram. amma mənə lazımdır ki, request.service.serviceName və ya request.service.serviceCategory hamısın ayrılıqda çağıra bilim. Çünki request.service yazanda yalnız toString ilə yazdığım qayıdır. Amma mənə ayrı-ayrılıqda lazımdır.

Comment: qardas sen reuqest.service.getServiceName yazib cagirandada hamisi gelir ?

Comment: he basa dusdum eziz

Comment: getter evezine sen onu bri basa yazirsan

Comment: Kodlarina baxiram heleki sehv gormurem

Comment: service ozu listdir onu foreach e salib yazdirmaisan ?

Comment: onda mence islemelidir

Comment: basa dusdum service foreache sal yoxla

Comment: @Zaur mən bunları html də istifadə edirəm. onu select option-a salıb gətirə bilirəm list kimi, amma <p> üçün necə gətirim bilmirəm. tək text kimi. əgər zoom da call etmək alınarsa, screen share edərdim.

Comment: @Zaur məncə o yaxşı fikirdi, sadəcə tək text kimi qayıtsın istəyirəm, bütöv Listi gətirməsin.  Bu request-ə uyğun olanı gətirsin.

Comment: isteyrisen yuxari elave edim example kimi ?

Comment: zəhmət olmasa edərdin. baxardım

Comment: Yaxsi gozle elave edirem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Thymeleaf example

```
<p>
  <span th:each="task : ${foo.tasks}">
     <span th:text="${taskStat.index} + ': ' + ${task.name}"></span>
  </span>
</p> 



<tr th:each="book : ${listBooksTest}">
        <td th:text="${book.id}">ID Book</td>
        <td th:text="${book.id_author}">ID Author</td>
        <td th:text="${book.title}">Title</td>
        </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   @GetMapping("/requests/view/{requestId}")
    public String requestDetails(@PathVariable(value = "requestId") long requestId, Model model) {

        Requests request = requestService.getRequestById(requestId);

        List<Clients> listClients = clientService.getAllClients();
        List<Services> listServices = serviceRepository.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("listServices", listServices);
        model.addAttribute("listClients", listClients);

        model.addAttribute("request", request);

        return "request_detail_modal";
    }
```

Yuxarıda list kimi gətirmişəm, onu burada td-ə gətirmək lazımdı.

```
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Xidmət</th>
                <td data-label="Xidmət" th:field="*{service}" th:text="{}"></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: yeni service elave edecen tr de each kimi fso

Comment: mence biraz ozun yoxla alinacaq ozune guven :))))

Comment: yoxladım elə, alındı . Çox sağ ol köməyin üçün. Bunu yazırdım pozurdum , çünki qırmızılayırdı bunu intellij, deyirdim düz deyiı. heç run etməmişdim. Run etdim alındı :D . Çox sağ ol təkrar köməyin üçün. <3 @Zaur

Comment: spring-lə ilk proyektimdi, xaricilərin dərsliklərində elə qarşıma hansı çıxırdısa th idi, ona görə mən də ondan istifadə edə-edə getdim.

Comment: Buyur qardas Xosdu

Comment: hə, elədim onu @Zaur . Amma  yenə bir problem yaranır, belə cür yazanda bütöv listi gətirir. Amma sırf bu request-ə uyğun olanı gətirməyi lazımdı.

Comment: sen dovre salanda service yazma reuqest.service yaz

Comment: elə yazdım alınmadı, amma th:each="ser : ${request.service}"  belə yazdım alındı. listServices i əvəzlədim request.service lə

Comment: @Zaur üzrlü say qardaş, əgər vaxtın varsa, oxşar bir problem var. Məhsul,Məhsul Kateqoriyası və Sifariş . Sifariş yaradanda, Kateqoriya seçirəm və istəyirəm  bu kateqoriyaya uyğun məhsullar qayıtsın. Bəyaxkı kimi edirəm, alınmır :/

Comment: Ama imkan varsa ingilis dilinde yaz

Comment: Paylasdinsa linki bura at imkan varsa

Comment: @Zaur  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67620276/how-i-get-value-category-and-categories-product-in-another-class-with-using-man